# While indexing the Postgres jsonb getting error

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I'm using Postgresql
My table is like that;

```
create table wine
(
   id       varchar(50) not null primary key, 
   payload  jsonb not null default '{}'::jsonb
);
```

Payload's Json view

```
{
"country": "US",
"province": "Planted in 1988, this vineyard  s fruit captures the unique minerality found in this AVA. It leaves an impression of sucking on rock—not a bad thing in a wine. The black-cherry fruit grips the palate with real power and some density, with potent herbal highlights as well. Drink this now through the mid-2020s.",
"variety": "Meredith Mitchell Vineyard",
"price": "90",
"description": "48.0",
"id": "976",
"designation": "Oregon",
"winery": "McMinnville",
"region_1": "Willamette Valley",
"region_2": "Pinot Noir",
"points": "Winderlea"
}
```

I want to index the field inside the payload which is id because I will search data with this id so do this I have wrote this function;

```
create or replace function jsonb_values_of_key(jsonb, wanted_key text)
  returns text
  language sql
  immutable
as $$
  select array_to_string(array(select attr.value from jsonb_array_elements($1) arrayElem, jsonb_each(arrayElem) attr WHERE attr.key=wanted_key),' ') 
$$;
```

then I try create a index;

```
CREATE INDEX wine_id_values_idx ON wine
  USING GIN (jsonb_values_of_key(payload, 'id') gin_trgm_ops);
```

after try creating the index I got this error

```
ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object
CONTEXT:  SQL function "jsonb_values_of_key" statement 1
SQL state: 22023
```

I just want to index the field inside the jsonb value what is my fault in this situation. If there if is there any other way could you please share with me? Thank you.

I want to make faster this query

```
select * from wine where payload @> '{"id": "{id}"}';
```

My road map is here: https://medium.com/@thegalang/indexing-in-postgresql-and-applying-it-to-jsonb-c99ecf50a443

I tried to create jsonb index but I got error while trying this.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add an example of the JSON value you are trying to index? And a complete example of the query that you are trying make faster with that index.

Comment: Kind of weird to try building an index using a function you have not tested even once.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because `jsonb_values_of_key` expects that its first argument is a JSON array, not a JSON object. When you create the index, you set `payload` as `jsonb_values_of_key`'s first argument, which means that `payload` should only contain JSON arrays and not JSON objects. Otherwise, if there is a row whose `payload` is not a JSON array, the indexing will fail on that row, so either the insert of the row or the creation of the index will fail, depending on which one is run second.

This [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nAKj8KLd) demonstrates the problem with using a JSON object instead of a JSON array.